# Add a timeout to load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var refreshId_hxlatestposts = setInterval(function() {
var el = $("#hxlatestposts");
var req = $.get("example.php");
el.fadeOut('slow', function () {
    req.done(function( data ){
        el.html(data).fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
}, 60000);
```

This is what i use to refresh a div every minute, sometimes it gets hung up when the site it is getting the feed from is down or something. I'd like to some how have a timeout so if it cannot load the php file in X seconds then return 'Fail to load'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery documentation ([.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)) suggests using `.ajaxSetup()` to set the value for `timeout`, instead of using it in individual requests.

You can use `request.fail()` to register a function in case of a failed request.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    timeout: 5000
});

var refreshId_hxlatestposts = setInterval(function() {
    var el = $("#hxlatestposts");
    var req = $.get("example.php");
    el.fadeOut('slow', function() {
        req.done(function(data) {
            el.html(data).fadeIn('slow');
        });
        req.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            el.html('Fail to load').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
}, 60000);
```

Comment: If i was to use X of this code snipped would i only have to to put ajaxSetup once at the top of the JS file? Nevermind i guess i should of read the documentation.

All subsequent Ajax calls using any function will use the new settings, unless overridden by the individual calls, until the next invocation of $.ajaxSetup().

Answer (score 2):

Nice use of deferred objects.

If you replace `$.get` with `$.ajax`, you can add a timeout.

```
var req = $.ajax({
    url: "example.php",
    type: "GET",
    timeout: 5000 // 5 seconds
});
```

and then add a fail handler

```
req.done(function(){...}).fail(function(){ 
    alert("failed to load"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to check the status of the incoming response to ensure that the service returned a 200 Ok status. This is more reliable than just waiting for a timeout-- you will know if it's good data or not an can decide to retry by putting your timeout in the complete functions.

```
   $.ajax({
    //...        
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        //handle status codes etc.
        // then set your timeout

    },
    complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        //handle status codes etc.
         // then set your timeout

    },

    // OR

    fail: function( xhr, textStatus ){
        //retry code or timeout
    }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's $.get is just a shorthand for $.ajax, which is used when more flexibility is required (in your case, yes)

Replace `$.get("example.php");` with:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "example.php",
  timeout: X*1000,
}).done(function(data) { 
   el.fadeOut('slow', function () {
     el.html(data).fadeIn('slow');
  });
}, 60000);
});
```

where `X` is number of seconds you would want it to wait (timeout)

Comment: Sry, i made some edits to the new code, so you can replace the code below `var el = $("#hxlatestposts");`